# how to move or arrange the code tabs in android studio

Tags: android-studio, shortcut

[image]

Thanks in advance to everyone who replies.

I want to know the shortcut key to move the 'date_edit_screen.dart' file to the left as shown in the figure upper.

No matter how much I searched for the shortcut map, I couldn't find it...

what should i do??